# What are the problems in analyzing an experiment with non-ideal collisions?

Tags: experimental-physics, collision, data-analysis

For a two-dimensional collision experiment, I must explain in one of the questions the problems in analyzing a non-ideal two-dimensional collision. As the question states:

> Suppose that the projectile marble and target marble do not collide with their centers of mass equidistant from the floor, as shown in figure 8.4. What problems in analyzing this experiment are cause by the non-ideal collision?

[image]

I am not so sure that I have everything or if it is a valid awnser, but so far I have concluded the following:**The Problems in analyzing non-ideal collisions or any other non-ideal conditions lies with either the decrease of precision of data, accuracy of data, or both.**

Note: For the sake of the quality of this post, I ask you to please feel free to make any edits so that people in the future can have this question answered. Also I thank everyone in advance for the contribution of this post.

Comment: This appears to have been asked before on at least 4 other websites over the past 10 years, including http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/suppose-projectile-marble-target-theyare-shot-collide-centers-ofmass-equidistant-floorinse-q596080, http://www.physforum.com/index.php?showtopic=44979, http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=48377, and http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=48371, with a PDF copy of the problem set available at http://www.uh.edu/~lwood/1121_EXP06_2D-Collision%20Inquiry.PDF. Have you tried reading through the threads posted by others?

Comment: Indeed I have, but their seems to be a lack of a general consensus. Some state on the physics forums that the question is unclear. Also I see that their answers seem a little unsure of what to write. In this case, I seek a valid answer to this if there is any validity to this question. Also +1 for making sure I am doing prior research.

Comment: I'm not really sure what "do not collide with their centers of mass equidistant from the floor" means. Is the projectile marble bouncing on the floor and therefore not equidistant from the floor at the time of the collision?

Further: What is the difference between "precision of data" and "accuracy of data"?

Comment: @Michael Große The percision of data is how close the experiment data is in each attempt: if your data has a difference of 0.1 vs. 1, then the data with the difference of 0.1 has greater precision. The accuracy of data is how close your experimental data to the consensus of others who did the same experiment: like the more times you hit the bulls-eye of a target, the greater the accuracy. Also to answer your first question, I believe equidistant in the contact of center of the balls. As shown in the picture of the question post in which I made an edit.

Comment: @MichaelGroße Also did you do prior research on the accuracy and precision of data before asking that question? Its quite a common scientific phrase used in all experiments. Sorry if I sound rude, but I am making sure of this because I am following the goal of stack exchange in which is having constructive statements in which help answer the questions. So basically no "Chit-Chat", but only valid constructive comments or answers. So in the spirit of all stack exchange sites, all members must do prior research before asking questions. I admire your curiosity, but please do research beforehand.

Comment: @Toltar. Yes I did. However "accuracy" is not well defined without context. "spread of the data over many events" or some reference to a standard deviation or spectrum might be less misleading.

Comment: @MichaelGroße +1 for verification of research. Also I agree with your decision to state that " "accuracy" is not well defined without context."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question sound to me a bit more hands-on than your general and abstract answer about precision and accuracy, even though your answer is not wrong.

The target marble will get some angular momentum. That may lead to a curved flight path due to the [Magnus effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect). This plays a role in many ball games, e.g. [basball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slider).

However this effect does not appear if your marbles are in a vacuum or if they are actually considered point-like.

Comment: I believe their may be a lot of answers to this question, so I believe this could possibly be another valid answer to this. Since this experiment revolves around momentum and kinetic energy, the Magnus effect seems to be a very valid answer. +1